# FAQ Page in Multiple store is shown only in one store

Tags: extensions, blocks, multistore, magento-1

I'm using Mage World EasyFAQ extension and I want to display the same FAQ page on multiple stores.

In CMS > Manage Page I have created a page. With the URL Key "faq", and linked multiple stores to that page.

In the WYSIWYG editor I have added this line:

```
{{block type="faq/faq" name="faq.list" template="faq/faq.phtml" }}
```

It works only on one store. It creates the questions and answers. 
But, on the other stores, it doesn't create the questions and answers.

I checked the HTML output through Firebug. 
On the working page it shows that in

```
    <div class="col-main">
<pre>
<div class="mw_faq">
<div class="mw_faq">
<div class="mw_faq">
</pre>
```

On some stores these div's with mw_faq classes aren't added.

Can you point me in the right direction in solving this problem?

Comment: I guess you are using Mage World FAQ extension? http://www.mage-world.com/easy-faq-magento-extension.html
Did you contact them for support already?

Comment: Yes, but I didn't do that.

Comment: Maybe you have to configure the FAQ questions/categories to be shown on both stores in the FAQ admin?

Comment: @7ochem I went to "EasyFAQ > Manage FAQ Categories", and I added the other stores to it. Its solved now.

Comment: I've put the solution into an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to configure the FAQ questions/categories to be shown on both stores in the admin at EasyFAQ > Manage FAQ Categories.